# Is inheritance of int, byte.. in .NET from object still justified?

Tags: c#, compilation, compiler-construction

I know that *"Each class extends a class object"* even value type like `int` extends/inherit from `object`. I suppose that one of the reasons is the possibility of storing objects of various types in the `Array` container in the pre-generic era.

**Does the application "in the real world" use the fact of inheritance** simple types (`int`, `float`...) from the `object`?

**Do we pay for it?** in the form of reduced speed or increased memory demand.

**Do we need it?**

I am working on a theoretical language and I wonder if inheritance `int`, `long`, `float` (simple types).. from the `object` will be useful in creating the application. 
From my point of view - this is more complicating the language syntax than simplifying it and there is no extra added value.

- override `ToString()` can be replaced with interface e.g `IToString`
- the generic container may contain int, long, float..
- `Integer` class as wrapper to `int` can be used in other cases

Comment: Do primitives implement interfaces in Java? What *already* enables them to do that in .NET, do you think... perhaps, inheritance from `Object`? No wrapper needed.

Comment: `java` tag may have been a bad idea. I was looking for Java user perspective on simple type inheritance, but that probably just obfuscated the question

Answer (score 1):

There are many places where the autoboxing feature of C# is very useful, like `Console.WriteLine()` or when you want to invoke a method by reflection or want to retrieve a value by reflection. And there are probably many more places that rely on the autoboxing. Of course one could introduce wrapper classes for the primitives as it is done in Java. I'd consider that a step backwards. Note that it is not enough to have a wrapper type for every primitive - you need them for all value types (including structs and enums). With real generics that could be done with a generic boxing class:

```cs
public class Box<T> where T : struct
{
    public Box(T value) => Value = value;
    public T Value { get; }
}
```

But at the end you cause a lot of work for the user, which is done by the runtime in dotnet.

Comment: If I understand the `Console.WriteLine ()` part correctly - simple types such as int do not require inheritance from `object` to be used in `Console.WriteLine()`, this can be done via an interface with the `ToString ()` function or a built-in function. But thanks for the interesting point of view with reflections

Comment: I think the specific overload that quinmars is noting is the one that takes a format string and a variable number of arguments. Java uses type information in the format specifiers, e.g. `%d` or `%s`, which tells it if a parameter on the stack is a primitive or a pointer to a class. This takes after C's `printf` because (I assume) it has the same limitations. .NET has *positional* markers, which take the type information from the instance because it's always a reference, even if it's a boxed `Int32`, for example.